# What's the justification for downvoting due to lack of effort?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, downvote-reason

The tool tip for downvotes reads 'This question does not show any research effort'.

[From another meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420776/adding-lack-of-effort-as-a-close-vote-reason)

> Simply put, we don't care if the author already knows the answer or if
> they are even interested in knowing the answer. **All we care about is
> whether they have produced a useful and answerable question.**

As far as I know, downvotes are primarily for signifying whether or not a question is useful for the community as a whole, either for people visiting the site looking for answers or people on SO looking to answer questions. We are often told on meta that we are voting for the question, not the user. To me, downvoting for lack of effort seems a bit like punishing the user rather than signifying whether it's a high quality, useful post.

Why introduce an additional reason for downvoting which is imperfectly correlated with posting quality and is necessarily subjective? What's wrong with just downvoting posts that are unclear or not useful? I can imagine a scenario where a user has provided a high quality question, but not put much research effort in, which can still be very useful for the community as a whole.

I totally understand why 'not clear' is a reason for downvoting, since clarity is directly related to how useful a question is; if it's unclear, it cannot be useful. That doesn't apply for effort.

For the record, I'm not necessarily disagreeing with the premise of downvoting for lack of effort, or defending people who put no effort into posts, I'm just unsure about the real justification.

Comment: I think it refers more to questions asking "How do I exit VIM", which has an obvious duplicate, or questions like "How do I add two numbers together in C" which is just ridiculously simple and thus not very useful. We are not punishing the user for not putting in enough effort, we are saying the question is not useful because the author hasn't done enough research.

Comment: Not always, but a lack of evidenced effort *can* suggest a lack of research as well, and "does not show research effort" is part of the tooltip for downvoting. This is especially true for questions like the one @Dharman describes ("How do I exit VIM") where often putting the question's title into your favourite search engine gives a wealth of resources that answers the question.

Comment: @Dharman OK, but why not just have 'This post is not useful' under the tooltip, why does effort have to come into it? Do we need to list several reasons why it's not useful? And why is lack of effort a reason for downvoting rather than say, being off-topic, which also renders a post not useful?

Comment: I always read the reasons in the tooltip as _potential_ reasons, not as "valid" reasons. It's information from the downvoted more than it is for the downvoter.

Comment: It's about a lack of "*research effort*", not a lack of "*effort*" in general.

Comment: Part of "research effort" includes correct terminology to describe what you are talking about (so we don't have to formulate a guess) and putting forth a plan to tackle the problem (even if it's incorrect, or not a good method);. --- You have to accurately describe: this is where I am, and this is how I thought I'd go about getting to where I want to be, which is *here*. --- Questions or answers that legitimately require a lot of clarification, and such is not edited back into the post, aren't as well researched as a post that is more straightforward. But, it doesn't always have to be simple.

Comment: "We are often told on meta that we are voting for the question, not the user". That's right. The statement "This question does not show any research effort" is a reflection of the question, not the user. The user may or may not have done research, but the question doesn't reflect it, and we vote accordingly. Sure, some low-quality questions turn out to be useful to the community now and then, usually by accident due to good answers and SEO. But they're _usually_ not useful by a wide margin. The idea is to curate better than "hope someone writes a high-quality answer to my no-effort question".

Comment: Pet peeve: questions that toss in something to the effect of "I tried a lot of things" with zero elaboration. This is unhelpful and doesn't _show_ research effort. Emphasis on showing research effort here, i.e. the exact code and strategies tried, the docs and posts referenced, etc. Simply telling people you tried hard doesn't exempt you from the "post shows no research effort" close vote because you're trying to satisfy a content requirement with a zero-content personal statement.

Comment: I have two comments here. First of all this is selective reading, the full tooltip is "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". The unclear and not useful bits are kind of important. Secondly there is a big difference between not doing research effort and not *showing* it. The tooltip specifically refers to not showing it. It makes no assumption about what the author did or did not do, it only refers to the quality of the question. We should make no assumptions in that direction either.

Answer (score 21):

#### Research effort, generally, means not re-asking duplicate questions

Note that the tooltip says "*research* effort", not just "effort".

[Quoting Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260909/208273) on the types of effort that can be put into a Stack Overflow post:

> 1. **Research effort:** has the asker searched for a solution before asking?
> 2. **Definition effort:** has the asker put enough thought into the problem to formulate a clear, specific question?
> 3. **Problem-solving effort:** has the asker done anything to solve the problem himself before asking?
>
> We have a close reason for #1: **Duplicate**.
>
> We have *multiple* close reasons for #2: Unclear, Too Broad and a grab-bag of more specific reasons under Off Topic.
>
> We *do not* have a close reason for #3

Downvoting questions that have obviously already been asked makes sense: they generally aren't useful, and consume time to find the original and close them as duplicates.

Sometimes, a duplicate may be non-obvious even with research, and that can serve as a useful signpost.  There wouldn't be a reason to downvote that if it's well-asked.

Answer (score 3):

Voting is our way to make good content, *for programmers*, **stand over** not so good content. We don't grant votes for efforts.

IHMO, the reason to downvote a question because it *doesn't show research effort* is when *obviously* that question was already "answered" and that answer is easy to find for someone with *basic coding literacy*, so it doesn't provide any value *to programmers*.

By programmers I mean a reasonable "anyone who writes code". The OP's background and the time that they invested prior making a question doesn't matter. Someway they decided to code, and they aren't just asking that someone else code for them, having themselves any interest on writing code. We asked them to show *research effort* to help us know that the question is valuable for other programmers and that it should stand over other questions.

---

Research effort mainly means to have spent some time searching SO for answers before posting a new question as we don't want people to waste their time

- posting a question that was already asked
- waiting for an answer that is already available
- scrolling through infinite search result lists

IMHO, the *research effort* requirement also includes to look seriously at "in your face" knowledge (aka documentation, help, readme, googling, SO ask a question guidance, etc.).

<sup>If the "fucking manual" requires a solid coding literacy, deep knowledge in programming stuff to be understood and/or applied, I will not consider it as "in your face knowledge" not matter of being freely available on the web, so not because something is in "the manual"  will warrant a downvote.</sup>